# How can I split and implement machine learning with Azure Durable Functions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-functions, mnist, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to implement machine learning to recognize and classify MNIST image data using Python and Durable functions.
Maybe Durable functions are not suitable for machine learning, but I would like to implement it.
I am not sure how to pass data between activity functions in Durable functions and how to split epochs during training.

First, an overview of the code.
The Net class and client functions do not need to be modified.
I would like to see proposed modifications to the Client function and Activity function.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import CSVLogger
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

class Net(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(588, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.conv(x)
        h = F.relu(h)
        h = self.bn(h)
        h = F.max_pool2d(h, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        h = h.view(-1, 588)
        h = self.fc(h)
        return h
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        train_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('train_acc', train_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        val_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('val_acc', val_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        test_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('test_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('test_acc', test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001) 
        return optimizer
#=========================================================================================================
# Client function
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:

    # Launching the orchestration
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    
    # Waiting for orchestration to complete
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

    # Obtaining the execution state of an orchestration
    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)

    # Getting the results of an orchestration run
    output = status.output
    return f"output:{output}" 


#=========================================================================================================
# Orchestrator functions
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
  # Preprocessing
    train, val, test = context.call_activity("pre_processing")

  # Learning. I don't know how to split the data in learning.
  # If I want to run 5 epochs in total, first run 3 epochs and then run the remaining 2 epochs
    net = Net()
    logger = CSVLogger(save_dir='logs', name='my_exp')
    batch_size = 256
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, deterministic=True, logger=logger)
    inputs = { "net": net, "trainer": trainer, "train": train, "val": val, "logger": logger, "batch_size": batch_size }
    yield context.call_activity("train_activity", inputs)

    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=2, deterministic=True, logger=logger)
    inputs = { "net": net, "trainer": trainer, "train": train, "val": val, "logger": logger, "batch_size": batch_size }
    yield context.call_activity("train_activity", inputs)

    ## Evaluation with test data. Get result ##
    return result

#=========================================================================================================
# Activity function

# Dataset Preparation
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="inputs")
def pre_processing(inputs: dict) -> list:
   # Define the transformation of the dataset
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_val = datasets.MNIST('./', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test = datasets.MNIST('./', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

   # Split into train and val
    n_train,n_val = 50000, 10000
    train, val = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_val, [n_train, n_val])
    return [train, val, test]
 

@app.activity_trigger(input_name="inputs")
def train_activity(inputs: dict):
    net = inputs["net"]
    trainer = inputs["trainer"]
    train = inputs["train"]
    val = inputs["val"]
    batch_size = inputs["batch_size"]
    logger = inputs["logger"]

    # Define Data Loader
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=batch_size)
    
    # Only some epochs are executed for learning.
    trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
   
    # return the results
    return trainer.logged_metrics
```

The following is a particular section of this that we would like to see corrected.
First, I want to make sure that this part of the data is passed correctly and that the code works.

```
# Orchestrator functions
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
  # Preprocessing
    train, val, test = context.call_activity("pre_processing")

  # learning training
    net = Net()
    logger = CSVLogger(save_dir='logs', name='my_exp')
    batch_size = 256
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, deterministic=True, logger=logger)
    inputs = { "net": net, "trainer": trainer, "train": train, "val": val, "logger": logger, "batch_size": batch_size }
    yield context.call_activity("train_activity", inputs)
```

I have tried to create a rough code like the one I just created, but it does not work. Also, it seems like a lot of data is being exchanged between functions.

To summarize what I have said so far,

- I want to implement machine learning for MNIST classification with Durable functions, but have not been able to do so.
- I want to ensure correct and minimal data exchange between functions
- (I want to split the learning epoch step)

Comment: `the code is long` yes, it's 158 lines; is there any way you can make it a [mre]?

Comment: Since the code was very long, we split it into the overall code and the parts that we especially wanted to have corrected.
First of all, I would like to fix the data passing between the orchestrator function and the activity function so that they work properly.